# What is the advantage of using Supplier in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

Reading about the new [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) interface I can't see any advantage of its usage.
We can see bellow an example of it.

```
class Vehicle{
  public void drive(){ 
    System.out.println("Driving vehicle ...");
  }
}
class Car extends Vehicle{
  @Override
  public void drive(){
    System.out.println("Driving car...");
  }
}
public class SupplierDemo {   
  static void driveVehicle(Supplier<? extends Vehicle> supplier){
    Vehicle vehicle = supplier.get();
    vehicle.drive();   
  }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Using Lambda expression
  driveVehicle(()-> new Vehicle());
  driveVehicle(()-> new Car());
}
```

As we can see in that example, the `driveVehicle` method expects a `Supplier` as argument.
Why don't we just change it to expect a `Vehicle`?

```
public class SupplierDemo {   
  static void driveVehicle(Vehicle vehicle){
    vehicle.drive();   
  }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Using Lambda expression
  driveVehicle(new Vehicle());
  driveVehicle(new Car());
}
```

What is the advantage of using `Supplier`?

**EDIT:** The answers on the question [Java 8 Supplier & Consumer explanation for the layperson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417262/java-8-supplier-consumer-explanation-for-the-layperson) doesn't explain the benefits of using `Supplier`.
There is a comment asking about it, but it wasn't answered.

> What is the benefit of this rather than calling the method directly?
>   Is it because the Supplier can act like an intermediary and hand off
>   that "return" value?

Comment: FWIW: `driveVehicle(Vehicle::new)`

Comment: Can somebody comment on the last part of the question - 'What is the benefit of this rather than calling the method directly?'?

Comment: @pMan Supplier is useful because it will be invoked only when and if necessary. For instance, if (condition) { doStuff(supplier.get()); }

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.Level-java.util.function.Supplier- and you'll understand.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your example above I'd not use a supplier. You are taking a `Vehicle` to drive, not requesting vehicles.

However to answer your general question:

- Because building a car is expensive and we don't want to do it until we really really need to.
- Because we want *X* cars not just one.
- Because the time of construction for a car is important.
- Because construction is complicated so we want to wrap it up.
- Because we don't know which Vehicle to return until we return it (maybe it will be a new one, maybe a recycled one, maybe a wrapper, who knows)

Comment: this doesn't make any sense in this context.

Comment: @mlk I was asking in a general way. Your answer is valid. Thank you.