# Java 8 + Constructor References

Tags: java, java-8

I am just trying learn some `java-8` stuff and came across this script.

```
public class ConstructorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonFactory<Person> personFactory  = Person::new;
        Person person = personFactory.create("Test", "User");
        System.out.println(person);
    }

}

interface PersonFactory<P extends Person> {
    P create(String firstName, String lastName);
}

class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    Person() {}

    Person(String firstName, String lastName) { this.firstName = firstName; this.lastName = lastName; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FirstName -> "+firstName + " : LastName ->"+ lastName;
    }

}
```

Which looks good. But my question is, rather going for this two lines of code

```
PersonFactory<Person> personFactory  = Person::new;
Person person = personFactory.create("Test", "User");
System.out.println(person);
```

I can better go can create my `Person` object in single with `new` keyword right?

```
Person person = new Person("Test", "User");
```

So what is the advantage does this `java-8` adding by providing this `Constructor References`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is more about what's the advantage of using the Factory pattern right?

Comment: I had the same doubt, but with `Functional Interface` we can able to have only one abstract method. So there is no point for factory

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960921/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-supplier-in-java

Comment: Note `BiFunction<String, String, Person>` would work just fine - you don't need your `iterface`.

Comment: The number of methods doesn't matter, a factory is a factory.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The interface provides clarity and abstraction.

Comment: @biziclop which might not needed for simple object creation right?

Comment: @biziclop that really depends. If you are publishing the `interface` as part of the API then yes. I would argue though, that if the `interface` is internal then there really isn't much need for it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think that even if it's internal, if its use is non-trivial (e.g. you use it from multiple locations in your code, or you pass it around a lot), you might want a specific interface. That way if you need to change the interface (say, add `middleName` parameter) you won't have to root around to find what effect it would have. But technically it isn't necessary, that's true.

Comment: @biziclop changing the interface will break the code just as effectively... But I get your point - _It Depends_ (TM).

Comment: @Suganthan What if the factory could return any implementation of an interface?

Comment: @OP I think as Holger says [in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29387876/2071828) - your example to too trivial to demonstrate the power of using a Factory. You are thinking too much in terms of this example, where indeed, calling `new` would make much more sense.

Comment: @BoristheSpider 
I agreed with both of you. | It’s just the same as with the “hello world” program

Comment: @biziclop Your point makes sense when I think about `middlename`