# passing instance method as parameter in java 8

Tags: java, methods, lambda, java-8

lets say I have

```
public class Student {
     public Integer getGrade() { return 1;}
}
```

and I want to pass this function as Function in java in other class(not Student)

which syntax will allow me doing so?

```
Function<Student,Integer> = ***
```

Answer (score 5):

Just do:

```
Function<Student,Integer> f = Student::getGrade;
```

You seem to have forgotten to put a name for the variable declaration!

Explanation:

`Function<Student,Integer>` represents a function that takes a `Student` as parameter and returns an `Integer`. Obviously, `getGrade` does not satisfy those criteria. But, since calling `getGrade` requires a `Student` object (because it's an instance method), the compiler can smartly use the `Student` parameter passed in to call `getGrade`.

If you don't understand what I mean, the syntax is equivalent to:

```
Function<Student,Integer> f = student -> student.getGrade();
```

Therefore, the below two lines are the same:

```
f(myStudent);
myStudent.getGrade();
```

Answer (score 4):

`Function<Student, Integer>` means "you take a student and return any `Integer` value":

```
Function<Student, Integer> f1 = student -> 2;
```

If you need a student grade, then return this value from the `getGrade` method:

```
Function<Student, Integer> f2 = student -> student.getGrade();
```

With the method reference, it might be written in a shorter form:

```
Function<Student, Integer> f3 = Student::getGrade;
```

Answer (score 1):

Being that `getGrade` isn't a static method, you'll need to first instantiate `Student` in order to store a reference to it.

```
Student student = ...;
Supplier<Integer> = student::getGrade;
```

You'll likely want to use a [`Supplier`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28446048/4297364) to store reference to the method because your method takes **no** input and returns one output (whereas a java [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) takes **one** input and returns one output).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
Function<Student, Integer> function = student -> student.getGrade();
```

or a method reference as

```
Function<Student, Integer> function = Student::getGrade;
```