# Use Connection to a Socket to check for Internet

Tags: java, android

I came across this code snippet to check for internet access by opening a Socket-

```
class InternetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

private Consumer mConsumer;
public  interface Consumer { void accept(Boolean internet); }

public  InternetCheck(Consumer consumer) { mConsumer = consumer; execute(); }

@Override protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) { try {
    Socket sock = new Socket();
    sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53), 1500);
    sock.close();
    return true;
} catch (IOException e) { return false; } }

@Override protected void onPostExecute(Boolean internet) { mConsumer.accept(internet); }
}
```

But how do I actually use this AsyncTask? 
In my `MainActivity`, I call `new InternetCheck().execute();` but how to pass the `Consumer` param to it? 
PS - I just started with Android so sorry for being a noob here.

Comment: Any minimal example to show the usage would be appreciated

Comment: It's always a good idea to read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). Android's docs are pretty good too.

Comment: This code is not correct. It treats too many cases as failures. For example, a `ConnectException: connection refused` would indicate that the Internet is accessible. It also leaks sockets in the failure cases. This doesn't do anything more than `InetAddess.isReachable()`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `new InternetCheck(consumer).execute()`

```
new InternetCheck(new InternetCheck.Consumer() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Boolean internet) {
                Log.d("Internet", "Internet Connection" + internet);
            }
        }).execute();
```

Comment: The class takes in a `Consumer` parameter, how to pass it?

Comment: @user8587865 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417262/java-8-supplier-consumer-explanation-for-the-layperson

Comment: @TheWanderer, thanks but I am still unable to process how should I pass `Consumer`

Comment: @ChandanSharma, please explain how to declare `consumer`. Have you tried running this code? Can you share a minimal example?

Comment: Please check it again you get the internet connection in accept() method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the instance of `Consumer` `interface` inside your `InternetCheck` AsyncTask

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 new InternetCheck(new Consumer() {
        @Override
         public void accept(Boolean internet) {
             if(internet){
               Log.e("INTENET_STATUS","Intenet is avilable");
             }else {
               Log.e("INTENET_STATUS","Intenet Not avilable");
             }
        }
  }).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass consumer parameter like this:

```
new InternetCheck(mConsumer).execute();
```