# Java: create instance of variable class

Tags: java

I have interface `Cat` that is implemented by classes `LolCat` and `FatCat`. My program needs to remember which type of `Cat` user wanted melt with next. I cannot instantiate the proper `Cat` yet, so I need to remember the class. How do I do this?

---

I tried:

```java
Class nextCatClass = FatCat.class;
```

But now I don't know how to instantiate it using a variable. `new nextCatClass()` is not a valid syntax. I also tried

```java
Class<Cat> nextCatClass = FatCat.class;
```

but now I get an "incompatible types" error.

---

Risking to annoy the heck out of Java users, here's what I'd do in Python:

```py
next_cat_class = FatCat
...
instance = next_cat_class()
```

Comment: This is possible, but messy.  Alternatively, can you just store, e.g., the string `"FatCat"` or `"LolCat"` in your list, and then do `if(catType == "FatCat") { return new FatCat(); } else { return new LolCat(); }`?  (Of course you may want to use enumerated types, etc., but just something using this principle?)

Comment: Regarding `Class<Cat> nextCatClass = FatCat.class;` read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po

Comment: @Tom I am not sure how I should proceed regarding the "possible duplicate". Technically it could answer my question, but I find the accepted answer of this question better (more elegant solution, at least in my case). Advice?

Comment: Nothing bad should happen with your question when you accept the duplicate. Then it works like a sign post to the other, duplicated question. But your question can still contain this answer. But you're still free to disagree with the duplicate. But mind that other users with at least 3000 reputation points can still vote to close your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lambda [Suppliers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417262/java-8-supplier-consumer-explanation-for-the-layperson):

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Supplier<Cat> lolCatSupplier = LolCat::new;
        Supplier<Cat> fatCatSupplier = FatCat::new;
        Cat lolCat = lolCatSupplier.get();
        Cat fatCat = fatCatSupplier.get();
        System.out.println(lolCat.getClass());
        System.out.println(fatCat.getClass());
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but now I need to learn what the heck are these :D

Comment: They are basically anonymous, single-method interface implementations - in a short syntax. [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: Neat solution, but you can also simply encapsulate the creational logic in a factory. This creational pattern returns you, based on your condition (class type, simple string or better yet an enum value), a class instance when you need it without writing the creational logic in the middle of your method. 

Simpler to understand, if lambdas are not that familiar to you...